# How do I get a list of all artists in a user's library?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I miss an overview of Artits in Spotify, something that iTunes for example provides. Now I wonder how would a script look like to retrieve all artists in a user library?

The code below does not do it. Suggestions very much appreciated!

```
function getAllAlbums() {
    var albums = models.Library.albums;
    var imageHTML = document.getElementById('albumsList');

    for(i=0;i<albums.length;i++){
        var link = document.createElement('li');
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = albums[i].uri;
        link.appendChild(a);
        a.innerHTML = albums[i].name;
        imageHTML.appendChild(link);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to add document in front of your imageHTML, document.imageHTML.appendChild(link).  It is hard to tell as I do not even know what your models.Library.albums does. I gess it return a Array with the Artis name in it.

Comment: What does the code do instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what iTunes functionality you're looking to replicate or what you're trying to do with the HTML, but if you're just looking for a list of artists, the [api](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/dcdebc652c.html) provides an easy way of accessing them.

Creating a list of all the artists in the users library is straight forward:

```
artistArray = models.library.artists
artistNameArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<artistArray.length; i++){
    artistNameArray[i] = artistArray[i].data.name;
}
```